# Add option of percentage in option tab in price of a product in the register in Opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.x

When you register a product that has multiple options, such as, for example, a course that has access to 30, 45, 60 and 90 days, and that each period has an increasing percentage.

For example:
30 days 0%
45 days 25%
60 days 35%
90 days 45%

At the moment, it is only possible to add a fixed value and not by percentage.

[image]